# Automatic deployment of files from a BitBucket repository

Tags: mercurial, ftp, continuous-integration, web-hosting, bitbucket

Is there a tool out there (preferably web-based) which would automatically detect commits to a BitBucket repository, and at that time, copy all files in the repository to a web-server via FTP?

I basically want a quick and painless way (if one exists) to set up continuous integration between my BitBucket repository and my website.

No build/compilation step would be necessary, since these are only front-end (HTML/CSS/Javascript) files.

Answer (score 4):

The `changegroup` hook is the way to do this. See [Hooks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook) for info about what to do with it.

I've used changegroup hooks on my own hg repositories, but not in BitBucket; it's possible that the BitBucket servers are restricted in what you can do, I'm not sure. I do know a wget/curl attempt to rebuild a manual upon my server upon updating its contents in a repository on SourceForge failed for me because they've locked up their servers too tightly (sending an email from the hook would work but not http access). I would expect BitBucket to be set up better; a quick search for "bitbucket changegroup hook" doesn't seem to indicate that there are any problems with it. Try it and see!